# Is it possible to add page layouts/web parts using a feature activated in a sub site?

Tags: feature, page-layout, web-part-page

I'm trying to keep my code as organized as possible, and in doing so wanted to create sub sites (sub projects) that contain their own page layouts and web parts etc. Is it possible for me to put these items into a feature that is to be activated on a sub site instead of the root site?

So far all of my attempts at this have failed. Using the same module xml that I have been using for the root site, I don't get any errors, but I also don't get my files added to the master pages or web parts catalogs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="MyProjectGroupsPageLayouts" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" Path="PageLayouts">
        <File Url="MyProjectGroupsWebPartPage.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
            <Property Name="Title" Value="My Project Groups Webpart Page" />
            <Property Name="MasterPageDescription" Value="My Project Groups Webpart Page which is a two column layout with secondary column on the left." />
            <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;" />
            <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType" Value=";#MyProject Article Page;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39008de149b2ef494b4db10b5c475493897b;#" />
        </File>
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. The Web Part and Master Page galleries are site collection scoped.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, this is pretty much what I thought, but I had hoped I was wrong.